# Deep copy on arraylist of objects

Tags: java

I am trying to deep copy list of objects from a global arraylist and return all the objects in my return function as below

```
ArrayList<Objects> list = new ArrayList<Objects>();

public Objects copy() {
        Objects copied = new Objects();
        ArrayList<Objects > newList = new ArrayList<Objects>();
        for(Objects  objs : list){
            newList.add(objs);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<newList.size(); i++ ){
            copied = newList.get(i);
        }
        return copied;
    }
```

But this function only returns the very last element in the list. How do I make the function return all values? For eg if there are 3 objects in the global list my function should return all the 3 values.

Also I do not want my function return type to be an `ArrayList<Objects>` ie I dont want to return an ArrayList of Objects

Is this possible? If so what am I missing?

Comment: You want to return all 3 values, but you don't want to return an `ArrayList<Objects>`?  If you return `Objects` it will only be one element.  So what **do** you want to return?

Comment: A method can only return one thing. What's the reason you don't want to return a list? BTW here you are doing a shallow copy. A deep copy creates new objects.

Comment: You simply return the last because you iterate over the entire list and always store the current item in `copied`.

Comment: That's not making a "deep copy".  All it is is a very expensive way to retrieve the last element of the source list.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the [Apache Commons Lang SerializationUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html) clone()?